# MySQL Insert where not exists query won't insert if even one row exists

Tags: mysql, insert, exists

I am having a pretty complicated query. What I have is a table with car parts (parts_list, about 600 rows) which contains some information about the part like it's name and if it's motor dependent or not. For motor dependency I am having two different queries, so this is the one with no motor dependency (0, I save it as a boolean). Most of the parts can be disassembled and broken into more parts, that's why I am saving the parts as a tree and in that query I take only the parts that can't be disassembled (tree leaves). This table represents only the list of possible parts. Now for each car model I save a row in another table (parts) and I stick the parts_list_id and model_id together and then the price and quantity. Now if I run the query it will successfully generate about 500 rows(taking only the leaf parts) in the table "parts" and it will do what I need. About 500 (leaf) parts for the model id. But sometimes I generate a row for another model for a specific part. And then the query doesn't make the rest 499 rows. It only works if WHERE NOT EXISTS select query gives back 0. If even one row exists it doesn't insert the rest. But it doesn't make sense to me, because shouldn't it check with different values like a loop?

```
INSERT INTO parts  (parts_list_id, model_id, motor_id)
SELECT      orig1.id, '" . $this->model_id . "', '0'
FROM        parts_list AS orig1
LEFT JOIN   parts_list AS orig2 ON ( orig1.id = orig2.parent_id )
WHERE       orig2.id IS NULL
AND         orig1.motor_dependent = '0'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT      t1.id
  FROM        parts_list AS t1
  LEFT JOIN   parts_list AS t2 ON ( t1.id = t2.parent_id )
  LEFT JOIN   parts ON ( parts.parts_list_id = t1.id )
  WHERE       t2.id IS NULL
  AND         t1.motor_dependent = '0'
  AND         parts.parts_list_id = t1.id
  AND         parts.model_id = :model_id
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the sql statement seems fine. If there is one row, NOT EXISTS returns false. And that is correct. No one row is inserted. Perhaps you want to put some different checks using parts_list_id NOT IN (*your subquery*) instead of NOT EXISTS.

NOT EXISTS express a condition for the set as a whole, NOT IN is used to determine if the set has the right items.

I hope to get it right. It is a little bit difficult to understand your domain just from a single statement.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that NOT EXIST is global for all rows. I managed to work it by locking both ids - the one from the subquery in the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause and the one from the SELECT query. But in any case I am not using the right keyword. NOT IN is what should be used.